# How to use 'extend all' and don't look for parents selectors?

Tags: css, less

I'm rewriting a big CSS file in Less. I have some considerations about how to use 'extend all'

Imagine you have this CSS:

```css
.bran {
    content: 'orphan';
    house: 'winterfell';
    ...
    wolf: 'Summer';
}

.snow {
    content: 'orphan';
    house: 'winterfell';
    ...
    wolf: 'Ghost';
}

.ned .bran{
    ...
    content: 'son';
}
```

Ok, .brand has many properties, and .snow sharing many with him. But when .bran is a child of .ned, many .bran properties will changed

So I try to write in less, something like:

```css
    .ned{
        .bran{
            ...
            content: 'son';
        }
    }

    .bran {
        content: 'orphan';
        house: 'winterfell';
        ...
        wolf: 'Summer';
    }

    .snow{
        &:extend(.bran all);
        ...
        wolf: 'Ghost';
    }
```

But in this case, the output will be:

```css
    .ned .bran,
    .ned .snow {
      content: 'son';
    }
    .bran,
    .snow {
      content: 'orphan';
      house: 'winterfell';
      wolf: 'Summer';
    }
    .snow {
      wolf: 'Ghost';
    }
```

But I need that output:

```css
    .ned .bran{
      content: 'son';
    }
    .bran,
    .snow {
      content: 'orphan';
      house: 'winterfell';
      wolf: 'Summer';
    }
    .snow {
      wolf: 'Ghost';
    }
```

How can I extend all, but don't extend for parent selectors?

Comment: `&:extend(.bran);` w/o `all`.

Comment: @seven but .bran has other many complex prop. and .snow use them. if i use w/o all, i will need to do extend:hover, extend.valid, extend.error etc...

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Currently `extend` is limited to either   `flat` or `all` behaviour (indeed that was not very good choice for initial implementation. See [#2101](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2101)).

Comment: As a workaround you can hide `.ned .bran` from `extend all` by using selector interpolation or so (abusing the fact that extend does not support "dynamic" selectors... for example use `.ned { @bran: bran; .@{bran} {...` instead of `.ned { .bran {...`).

Comment: @seven, thks for the help and link to __issue__! And your approach with `@{}`  is very smart!